# First buffer (the [No Name] buffer) is not empty when I start Vim

Tags: buffers

I am a new vim user, and I don't know why but my first buffer (the [No Name] buffer) is not empty each time I open it, still after rebooting my computer.

It begins with `:q!` then the end of my .vimrc file.

And when I open a file with vim from the command line it says before :

```
"client.c" "client.c" 58L, 1558C 
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

And then a buffer with the file content preceded by the same text as when I open vim without opening a file, like described before.

I may have done something wrong but I don't know what and I haven't found any information about how to change the default buffer.

*Edit:* The text begins by :

```
:q!¬                                                                        
 ¬
 " Add plugins to &runtimepath¬
 call plug#end()¬
 ¬
 " Syntastic¬
 set statusline+=%#warningmsg#¬
 set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}¬
 set statusline+=%*¬
 ¬
 let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1¬
 let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1¬
 let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1¬
 let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0¬
 ¬
 ¬
 " Window navigation with Control¬
 nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>h¬
 nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j¬
 nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k¬
 nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l¬
 " Tab navigation¬
nnoremap th  :tabfirst<CR>¬  
nnoremap tj  :tabnext<CR>¬
nnoremap tk  :tabprev<CR>¬
nnoremap tl  :tablast<CR>¬
nnoremap tt  :tabedit<Space>¬
nnoremap tm  :tabm<Space>¬
nnoremap td  :tabclose<CR>¬
nnoremap tn :tabnew<CR>¬
nnoremap to :tabonly<CR>¬
nnoremap ts :tab split<CR>¬
```

Comment: Could you post a few lines from your _vimrc_, the lines just before the part from your _vimrc_ that shows up in the buffers?

Comment: I've updated the post. You can see the  `:q!` followed by the end part of my `.vimrc`.

Comment: Great, but I was looking for the lines just _before_ the part that shows up :) My guess is that you do something in your _vimrc_ that causes it to stop processing the lines as ex commands and instead input it as text into whatever first buffer you are loading. Maybe you can add five lines to the top, or even share your whole _vimrc_ if it is not too large?

Comment: I don't suppose you have a literal `:q!` in your _vimrc_?

Comment: I'm afraid I had this in my vimrc ! The problem is solved, thank you. I feel so dumb, why haven't I thought of this ?That's because I didn't know how vim responds to incorrect vimrc file... Again, thank you.

Comment: No problem :) happy vimming

Comment: @jjaderberg do post an answer.

Comment: muru: okidoke. NicolasScottoDiPerto: Vim is difficult and makes fools of us all from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the lines of your *vimrc* are input as text into whatever buffer you are loading.
It looks like there is something happening in your *vimrc* which stops the lines being processed as ex commands and instead are input as text into the buffer.
Look at the lines in your *vimrc* just at that break point and you may find the culprit.

Do you by any chance have a literal `:q!` in there?

Answer (score 2):

If the `vimrc` contains errors like literal

```
:a!
:q!
```

it will print the rest of the file in the first buffer, and also at the beginning of files opened.

So be sure to check your `vimrc` from errors.